# Center Text in Custom Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to customize my combobox like this image.

[image]

My code worked fine.But It's having 2 issues:

1.the text move to the left when I minimize the window as below

[image]

2.the background turn to green when another window cover my application.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
//DrawItem
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   e.DrawBackground();
   e.DrawFocusRectangle();
   if (e.Index >= 0) {  
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   Brush brs = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
   new SolidBrush(SelectedBackColor) : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
   g.FillRectangle(brs, e.Bounds);
   using (StringFormat sformat = new StringFormat()) {
    sformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, sformat);
}
//paint
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   if (index >= 0) {  
      using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor)) {
        StringFormat sformat = new StringFormat();
        sformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, br, this.ClientRectangle, sformat);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Resource1.arrow,this.ClientRectangle.Right - 34, 0,32,32);
      }
   }
}
```

so what is wrong?

Comment: your code doesn't compile; at least two closing curlies are missing. Please post only real code! - Do `e.Bounds` and/or `ClientRectangle` actually leave space for the arrow? Other than that: The error situations sounds funny.. After minimizing, and, I presume restoring, does the alignment/placement stay wrong?

Comment: sorry for my mistake.yes, I think the problem is e.Bounds. Combobox size is 135, 34 and e.Bouds is 133. When minimizing the window, e.Bounds is 112. e.Bounds resizes when minizing. How to fix it?@TaW

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Graphics.MeasureString` to get the size of the string to draw and then decide where to start drawing the string:

```
SizeF size = new SizeF();
size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font);
PointF DrawPoint = new PointF((this.Width - size.Width)/2, (this.Height - size.Height)/2);
e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, br, DrawPoint, sformat);
```

Comment: sorry for my late.Nothing changes.I'm looking for the way to fix e.Bounds and selected item style when the window minimize@Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem is DropDown state.I have to check DroppedDown out before set Brush.

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   e.DrawBackground();
   if (e.Index >= 0 && DroppedDown) {  
   Brush brs = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
   new SolidBrush(SelectedBackColor) : new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brs, e.Bounds);
   using (StringFormat sformat = new StringFormat()) {
        sformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, sformat);
}
```